# extend extent of geoJSON layer - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, features, extents

I am zooming to the extent of a set of geoJSONs collected in a FeatureGroup with this call:

```
 map.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup.getBounds());
```

...I would like to extend the extent a bit; as it is the extent is right on the edge of the geoJSON.

Is there a way to do this? I am new to Leaflet (I am more familiar with the ArcGIS JS API, where i would use:

```
map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet's `map.fitBounds` [has an option `padding`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitboundsoptions) which you can use like so:

```
map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds(), { padding:[50,50] } );
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1vjqjx6h/